# Why is my array being printed incorrectly?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I have written a simple program that reverses an array. For example, the string 'hello' would be printed out as 'olleh'. However, when I input something like 'hello', it prints out half the string reversed, followed by some cryptic characters and other nonsense that shouldn't be there.

My source code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100], temp;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
//  scanf("%s", &str);

    j = strlen(str) - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = str[temp];
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    printf("The reversed string is: %s", str);

    return (0);
}
```

Some of the output I get is 'oll' then a small square with four numbers inside. This can vary, sometimes printing 'olx' or 'olH' or even 'ol' with a question mark in a diamond shape. Why is my program not working as it should? Does the array already contain some other encoded information?

Comment: Shouldn't it be str[j] = temp; instead of str[j] = str[temp]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at these two lines:

```
temp = str[i];
...
str[j] = str[temp];
```

In the first you set `temp` to the character in `str[i]`. The other you use `temp` as the *index* into `str`. But `temp` is not an index, it's a character. So the last line should be

```
str[j] = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my confusion. My writing just gets clumsy when I'm tired ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is fine. You just need to replace

```
str[j] = str[temp];
```

by

```
str[j] = temp;
```

Comment: Oh, now I see, it was just a silly mistake I made when writing it. But I don't get how the two lines are different. Aren't they both just making `str[j]` equal to `str[i]`?

Comment: Oh wait, now I get it. It's because `str[i]` actually represents a character so `str[temp]` is basically saying `str[str[i]]`, which you cannot have because you cannot reference an element with a character.